# First and Second derivatives differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

The equation $x^5y + x +y^3 =3$ defines implicitly a function $y=g(x)$ near $x=1$. Compute $g(1)$ , $g'(1)$, and $g''(1)$.

If someone could show me the first few steps that would help.

Comment: What do you know about implicit differentiation? Where would you start?

Comment: Well I know that I have to derive for y but that's pretty much it

Comment: can anyone help me??

Comment: differentiate the constraint  $x^5g+ x +g^3 =3 $ with respect to $x$ twice.

Comment: could you show me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the constraint $$x^5y + x +y^3 =3\tag 1$$

putting $x = 1,$  gives you $y+y^3 = 2$ and the only solution is $y = 1.$
differencing $(1)$ we get $$x^5\, \frac{dy}{dx} + 5x^4y+1+3y^2 \, \frac{dy }{dx}= 0 \tag 2$$  putting $x = 1, y = 1$ should give you $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac32.$

i will let you difference $(2)$ and sub the values $x = 1, y = 1, \frac{dy}{dx} = -3/2$ to get the value of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}.$